# How do I see all my failed login attempts (macOS High Sierra)

Tags: macos, command-line, high-sierra, login, logs

I've tried the following commands:

```
syslog -F raw -k Facility com.apple.system.lastlog | grep <my_username>
cat /var/log/asl.log (DOES NOT WORK ON HighSierra)
who
```

Thanks to Scot, the following command works:

```
log show --predicate '(eventMessage CONTAINS "Authentication failed")' --style syslog --last 1d
```

The problem with this is that it does not give me the username of the account trying to be accessed.

Does anyone of any bash/Python programs or Terminal commands that will give me my failed login attempts (graphical login/ssh)?

See more info [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/8cs38d/failed_login_attempts_high_sierra/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to see Username of the failed and successful login attempts on my Mac High Sierra and ended up posting another question on SE. Later I found the answer and updated that post.

If you're still looking for a way to see usernames in logs then you need to turn on "private" mode for logs. Here is the command to do that:

```
sudo log config --mode "private_data:on"
```

Here is my post where I've posted this answer already:

[Mac OS High Sierra how to see Username for the failed login attempt](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336034/mac-os-high-sierra-how-to-see-username-for-the-failed-login-attempt/336123#336123)

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve the failed login with a command like the following:

For streaming data:

`log stream --predicate '(eventMessage CONTAINS "Authentication failed")' --style syslog`

Or, failed logins in last hour:

`log show --predicate '(eventMessage CONTAINS "Authentication failed")' --style syslog --last 1h`

But, this won't show the username for the failed request, only that a failure occurred.

Comment: This should be what I need...I'll test it first. Running test now.

Comment: This command takes too long to run! After 20-ish hours, it still hasn't picked up any fails, even though I purposefully entered some characters wrong.

Comment: Hmm - it should be virtually instant. And, the `log show` command should pick up any failures that have happened previously. Try the below command, it takes a few seconds to run on my machine.

Comment: `log show --predicate '(eventMessage CONTAINS "Authentication failed")' --style syslog --last 1d`

Comment: The above commands should show all failures that occurred in the last day, so your previous tests should come up...

Comment: Running your command now. Alright, now that it is done, it gives me the results (VERY FAST), BUT is there a way to get the username that was attempting to be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like Apple logs every login failure, or at least I'm not seeing a log with all login failures. I locked my screen and failed to log in and it didn't seem to record it anywhere.

However, the file /private/var/log/system.log does have some authentication failures listed.

> Apr 16 20:22:34 My-MacBook-Pro sudo[50638]:     username : 3 incorrect
>   password attempts ; TTY=ttys000 ; PWD=/Users/username ; USER=root ;
>   COMMAND=/usr/bin/su

You'll also see these messages in Console.app

[image: Console.app login failure]

Comment: Processing the log files isn't a great strategy now that Apple's unified logging is database driven. See Scott's answer on using the log command to stream and search the logs for these details. No -1 since you clearly offered help, just can't +1 this answer as it stands.